# Select only if condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not really sure if I have the correct title for this Q. anyway I'm trying to parse a delimited string into a list of Enum elements:

```
public enum MyEnum { Enum1, Enum2, Enum3 }
```

Given an input of:

```
string s = "Enum2, enum3, Foo,";
```

I would like to output only the parts that exists in `MyEnum` (ignoring the case):
`[MyEnum.Enum2, MyEnum.Enum3]`

```
IEnumerable<MyEnum> sl = 
    s.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)                         
    .Select(a => { if (Enum.TryParse(a, true, out MyEnum e)) return e; else return nothing ??? })
```

How do I return "nothing" from the `Select()` if `TryParse()` fails?
I could do an ugly thing like:

```
IEnumerable<MyEnum> sl = 
    s.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)                
    .Where(a => Enum.TryParse(a, true, out MyEnum dummy))
    .Select(a => Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), a, true));
```

Doing the parsing job twice for no good reason,
But I'm sure I'm missing something trivial.
How can this be done in an efficient and elegant way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's super simple if you use nullable values for the `enum`:

```
IEnumerable<MyEnum> sl =
    s
        .Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(a => { if (Enum.TryParse(a, true, out MyEnum e)) return (MyEnum?)e; else return null; })
        .Where(x => x.HasValue)
        .Select(x => x.Value);
```

You can even reduce it down further:

```
        .Select(a => Enum.TryParse(a, true, out MyEnum e) ? (MyEnum?)e : null)
```

---

Or you could use `SelectMany` and avoid the nullables:

```
IEnumerable<MyEnum> sl =
    s
        .Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .SelectMany(a => Enum.TryParse(a, true, out MyEnum e) ? new[] { e } : new MyEnum[] { });
```

Comment: If the provided string is `"Enum2, enum3, Foo, 4"` then the result will contain `4` as well, even though it is an out of range int.

Comment: @PeterCsala, Thanks for this. I modified the above `Select()` condintion: `.Select(a => Enum.TryParse(a, true, out TEnum e) && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), e) ? (TEnum?)e : null)`

Comment: @Enigmativity, Do you know if the sequence (after the Split) will be iterated only *once* internally in such case?

Comment: @zig - Yes, it is only once.

Answer (score 3):

You can designate the value `-1` to be an invalid enum value thereby serving as a placeholder for any invalid strings and allow them to be subsequently excluded.  Also, this avoids parsing the strings more than once.

```
var invalidEnum = (MyEnum) (-1);

var sl = s.Split(new char[] {',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(a =>
    {
        var isValid = Enum.TryParse(a, true, out MyEnum myEnum);

        return isValid ? myEnum : invalidEnum;
    })
    .Where(a => a != invalidEnum);
```

Potentially `-1` could already be used by the enum if explicitly defined (unlike in the original example where default minimum is zero (`0`) so using `-1` is ok).  To minimize this risk the following values could be used instead of `-1`:

```
var invalidEnum = (MyEnum) (int.MinValue);
// or
var invalidEnum = (MyEnum) (int.MaxValue);
```

If still some concern that these highly unlikely values being taken then could find the next available number not used by the enum and assign it as the invalid enum:

```
var invalidEnum = (MyEnum) int.MinValue;

foreach(var number in Enumerable.Range(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue))
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), number))
    {
        invalidEnum = (MyEnum) number;
        break;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice trick :) I didn't even know such cast was legal. +1 for that. however if I want this to be a general/generic solution I can't assume anything about the underlying values of the enums.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the `Enum.TryParse` do the heavy lifting it is sub-optimal. It can generate false-positive result.

For example, if your `s`  string looks like this:

```cs
string s = "Enum2, enum3, Foo, 4";
```

then `Enum.TryParse` will able to convert `Enum2`, `enum3` and `4` to a valid `MyEnum` instance.

In order to filter out `4` from the result set you have to call `Enum.IsDefined`. Here is a sample how can you combine `TryParse` and `IsDefined`:

```cs
s.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Where(value => Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(value, ignoreCase: true, out var parsedValue) && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), parsedValue))
  .Select(value => (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), value, ignoreCase: true))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: `Enum.IsDefined` does not work on `string`, the statement that '`IsDefined` is case sensitive' does not make sense

Comment: Thanks. You can modify the condition to avoid double parsing e.g.: `.Select(a => Enum.TryParse(a, true, out TEnum e) && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), e) ? (TEnum?)e : null)` using nullable types as suggested by @Enigmativity

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LINQ aggregate method that can be used for cases like this:

```cs
var sl= s.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Aggregate(new List<MyEnum> (),(List<MyEnum> enums,string a)=>
                {
                    if (Enum.TryParse(a, true, out MyEnum e))
                    {
                        enums.Add(e);
                    }

                    return enums;

                });
```

Comment: While the above works, I'd hardly say that `Aggregate()` was _designed_ for this scenario. Indeed, it seems a bit heavy-handed for this particular use.

Comment: My understanding is that aggregate is essentially a reduce function, which is basically  what is needed in this case. I agree that there are many simpler ways of achieving this eg. a loop.

Comment: _"which is basically what is needed in this case"_ -- that's debatable, both because of the way you're using "reduce" here, and because `Aggregate()` is obviously not _needed_ here (as in "required"). But even if one accepts your statement at face vaue, LINQ provides simpler "reduce" semantics for this type of scenario that don't require materializing a whole collection just to produce a sequence of values.

Comment: What are the simpler reduce semantics that would have avoided creating the list (or are you referring to a different collection)? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Again, that comes down to how you're using the word "reduce". But see the other answer for examples. It is sufficient to create an intermediate value, filter on that, then project to the final desired type. This allows for materialization of only a single element at a time as the sequence is processed, no intermediate list or other collection object needed. Either you agree that alternative also is a "reduce" operation, or you agree that the problem doesn't actually _require_ a "reduce" operation.

Answer (score 1):

After you have divided your string s into substrings, you only want to keep only the enum values of the substrings that are proper myEnums.

You already knew how to divide your original string into substrings:

```
string s = ...
var subStrings = .Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Use a Select to try to parse each subString into a nullable MyEnum. If that fails, the nullable has no value; otherwise the nullable has the MyEnum value.

Remove the nullables that have no values, and Select the Values of the remaining ones:

```
var result = subStrings.Select(subString => new
{
    if (Enum.TryParse(subString, true out MyEnum parsedEnum)
    {
        return new Nullable<MyEnum>(parsedEnum);
    }
    else
    {
        return new Nullable<MyEnum>(null);
    }
})
.Where(nullableEnum => nullableEnum.HasValue);
.Select(nullableEnum => nullableEnum.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep a list of `MyEnum` type. not a list of strings. so you need to `Select()` and Parse  your `result` into `MyEnum`.